# how to import only selecte row from datagridview to rdlc report in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

i am having an rdlc report like this;

[image]

and a datagridview like this; on another wpf window which also contains my buttonimport;

[image]

My major aim is to import only (any) one selected row from the datagridview on to the rdlc report.
such that each row as selected will show up the values as selected in the mapped one;
For example:
if Row 1 is selected and the button import is clicked the value of the selected row columns will show according to there mapping in dataset1 to rdlc designed table;

here is my ReportViewer_Loaded code;(

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("DataSet1");
       string cnString = @"Data Source=SQLServer;Initial Catalog=Demo;Integrated Security=True";
       string sqlCmd = "SELECT MATH, ENGLISH, SCIENCE FROM Table1";
       using (da sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd, cnString)) da.Fill(dt);
       ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource() {Name = "DataSet1", Value = dt};
       reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\\Users\\hp\\source\\repos\\SMSKICSO\\SMSKICSO\\myReports\\TermlyReport.rdlc";
       reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
       reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

and here is my buttonimport_Click event code;

```
DataTable dtRep = ((DataView)dataGrid.ItemsSource).Table.Clone();
         for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
         {
             dtRep.ImportRow(((DataRowView)dataGrid.SelectedItems[i]).Row);
         }
         dtRep.AcceptChanges();
         TermlyReportShower window1 = new TermlyReportShower(dtRep);
         window1.ShowDialog();
```

i am working in wpf every code shown here works without error code but the problem i am having is that each time a particular row is selected from the datagrid to be shown, and the buttonimport is clicked all three rows from datagridview shows up in the rdlc report. and this is not what i want, i only want to show one row as selected by the user in the rdlc report please can some one help me to achieve this aim
i have tried many many code non seems to meet my expectation please am begging the prodigies here to help. (thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedRows` will help you get the collection of selected rows.

For safety, you could check if you have selected rows or not by doing:

```
if (dataGrid.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
   //Some code here
}
```

(1) Create a new `DataTable` for your report:

```
DataTable dtRep = new DataTable();
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGrid.Columns)
    dtRep.Columns.Add(column.Name, column.CellType);
```

(2) Add the selected rows to your report `DataTable`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
{
     dtRep.Rows.Add();
     for (int j = 0; j < dataGrid.Columns.Count; j++)
     {
         dtRep.Rows[i][j] = dataGrid.SelectedRows[i].Cells[j].Value;
     }
}
```

Finally, Put (1) and (2) into `//Some code here`